# Which Method is applicable

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

what method is used to solve an differential equation initial value problem as the one below:

$$y'' + 2y' + y = -2; \quad y(0) = 1, \; y'(0) =2$$

I just need to know the method we use so I can look it up and proceed from there.

Comment: Are you familiar with the characteristic algebraic equation of a homogeneous differential equation? That's the starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I first provided the most efficient methods for this problem.

**Hint**: Methods of constant coefficients and judicious guessing (or undetermined coefficients) work for this problem.

**Hint**: First, find the homogeneous solution by method of constant coefficient.  Then, for the particular solution, use method of undetermined coefficients.

$$\Large{\textbf{Other Approaches}}$$

**Second Approach**: Apply Laplace transform for the initial-value problem.  Transform IVP into the Laplace problem.

**Third Approach**: First, use the method of constant coefficients to determine the homogeneous solution.  Then, use the method of variation of parameters to determine the particular solution.

Answer (score 1):

Why make it so complicated? The characteristic equation is $t^2+2t+1$, its only root is $-1$, so the general solution of the homogeneous equation is $$y_0(x)=Ae^{-x}+tBe^{-x}.$$ The right side is a constant, so we look for a constant solution of the equation, which is obviously $y_1(x)=-2.$ So the general solution is $$y(x)=Ae^{-x}+tBe^{-x}-2.$$ Using the initial values one gets $A=3$ and $B-A=2$, that is $B=5$.

Comment: Can you explain why you did: >The right side is a constant, so we look for a constant solution of the equation

Comment: Are we looking for a solution for the non-homogenous equation? I'm not understanding why we add $-2$ to our general solution

Comment: The general solution of the non-homogeneous equation is given by the sum of the general solution of the associated homogeneous equation and a particular solution of the non-homogeneous one. When the right side (of the n.h., of course) is constant and $y$ appear on the left one, there is always a constant solution, the value of which is in fact the value of the right side.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to find a general solution to the ODE: $y''+2y'+y=-2$ and put initial data to the general solution.